# Strange behavior: running the same command twice in the same environment acts different than one each in two environments

Tags: macros, environments, counters

**Edit Preface**: Surprised this wasn't downvoted into oblivion as it was a really terribly written question... this is what I get for posting without thinking at 2am after a long day of coding... sorry guys.

I have determined the nature of the error, although why the blank environment helped I have no idea, so I have completely rewritten the question so it's clear including a useful MWE.

**Question**:

It seems that a \begin environment resets logic checks to false?

Observe the code below:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newif\iffooLogic
\fooLogicfalse

\newcommand{\fooCommand}{
%Don't include \fooLogicfalse here to make the problem
\iffooLogic
    {The First Is True!}
\else
    {The First is False!}
\fi

%Set \fooLogic to true for next line
\fooLogictrue

\iffooLogic
    {The Second is True!}
\else
    {The Second is False!}
\fi
% No reset of \fooLogic to false to create problem.
}

\newenvironment{testOne}{•}{•}
\newenvironment{testTwo}{•}{•}

\begin{document}


First let's do two in the same environment:

\begin{testOne}
\fooCommand 

\fooCommand
\end{testOne}


Now, nested empty environments

\begin{testOne}
%First
    \begin{testTwo}
    \fooCommand 
    \end{testTwo}

%Second
    \begin{testTwo}
    \fooCommand
    \end{testTwo}

\end{testOne}

\end{document}
```

This outputs:

```
First let’s do two in the same environment:
The First is False!
The Second is True!
The First Is True!
The Second is True!
Now, nested empty environments
The First is False!
The Second is True!
The First is False!
The Second is True!
```

Notice how (since I never reset \fooLoggic to false) the first environment returns the first as false, and all others as true.

However, when I nest an empty environment (like in the second environment example) it does one false and one true each. So it appears that exiting the empty environment is resetting the \fooLogic check.

1. Is this because it lacks a \global command on the logic set in the command \fooCommand?
2. Is this just environments that reset them, or is it because I'm exiting a shell of any kind (environment, command, for loops, etc) that the value gets reset without a \global?

Hopefully this is vastly more readable/sensible. Sleep is helpful.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do but rather than having `\setcounter{fooCount}{0}`, which sets `footCount` to zero, wouldn't it be better to have `\refstcounter{fooCount}` or `\addtocounter{fooCount}{1}`, which both increment `fooCount`?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify;
The stepcounter is happening inside the FILE independently. And I need that count for something else. So at the end of the command I reset it to 0, so that if/when I call the command again later it will count correctly.
In reality that FILE may be one of several, so I need to count the parts in the given file... it's not always the same number.
That being said; is there a difference between refstcounter and stepcounter? I haven't been able to find any distinction.

Comment: It would be far better for you to provide something that replicates the problem. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see what you're experiencing. Yes, the actual code.

Comment: If you use `\refstepcount` then it will be picked up by the next `\label` comment whereas if you use `\stepcounter` then the next `\label` will ignore the corresponding counter. As Werner says, it would be better if you can post a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: If you do `\newcommand{foo}` you get an error; if you do `\newenvironment{foo}{...}{...}` and then try to do `\newcommand{\foo}{...}` you get an error as well. Please, make a sensible example, because this one isn't.

Comment: Fixed question because phrasing was trash. Hopefully this is vastly more readable and sensible what I was trying to ask. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The sequence `\newenvironment{BAR}{<Arg1>}{<Arg2>}` defines `\BAR` to expand to `<Arg1>` and `\endBAR` to expand to `<Arg2>`. `\begin{BAR}<body of environment>\end{BAR}` forms a new **local scope/group**  and **inside that local scope** LaTeX executes: 1. `\BAR`, 2. `<body of the environment>`, 3. `\endBAR`.  If you put `\fooCommand` into the body of an environment, any (non-global) assignment done by `\fooCommand`  (e.g. ,`\fooLogictrue`) will take place **restricted to the local scope** formed by that environment.  The effect of the assignment does not reach beyond the environment's end.

Comment: Ah ha, that's exactly what I needed to know.
Thank's (again) Ulrich!

Comment: @Jason: The usual way to say 'Thank you' is to accept the given answer (here by Ulrich Diez) ;-)

Comment: Can I accept a comment? The submitted answer needs to be edited to reflect the actual asked question (which Ulrich did answer in his reply above).

Answer (score 1):

1. Spaces in the .tex input file behind something that gets tokenized as character token get tokenized as space tokens yielding (often unwanted) horizontal space in the pdf-file.
2. `\newcommand{foo}...` does not work out. Must be `\newcommand{\foo}...`.
3. `\newenvironment{foo} ...` roughly speaking defines the commands `\foo` and `\endfoo` and the `\begin{..}`-`\end{..}`- mechanism executes these commands inside inside a local scope/group. Therefore `\newenvironment{foo}{..}{..}...\newcommand\foo{...` yields an error about `\foo` being already defined.
4. `fooCount` is undefined.
5. `\input(FILE)` should probably be something like `\input{FILE}`. (La)TeX usually uses curly braces not parentheses for macro arguments.
6. If yout input file uses `\ifthenelse` then the package providing that command should be loaded.
7. If a file is loaded several times by `\input`, then it should not contain `\newcommand` as at the second loading this will raise errors about the control sequence in question being defined already.

Having said these things, the following code might probably do to a certain degree what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Here comes David Kastrup's \replicate macro, see
% <http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2005p/david-kastrup/bachotex2005-david-kastrup-pearl3.pdf>
\newcommand\recur[1]{\csname rn#1\recur}%
\newcommand\rnm[1]{\endcsname{#1}#1}\newcommand\rn[1]{}
\newcommand\replicate[1]{\csname rn\expandafter\recur
\romannumeral\number\number#1 000\endcsname\endcsname}


%Let's create file.tex that executes 500 \goo{5}:
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
%% Let's do 500 `\goo{5}`:
\replicate{500}{\goo{5}}%
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{fooCount}

\newcommand{\goo}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{#1 = 5}{%
    \stepcounter{fooCount}% Keep track of how many times #1 is 5
    %SomeCode
  }{}%
}%

\newenvironment{foo2}{%
  (This has some code that will hide some output, but not
   suppress it from running in the code)%
  \ignorespaces
}{\ignorespacesafterend}%

\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \input{file.tex}% FILE has a bunch of "\stepcounter{fooCount}"
  \arabic{fooCount}%
  \setcounter{fooCount}{0}%
}%

\newenvironment{foo3}{\ignorespaces}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo2}
\foo
\foo
\end{foo2}

\begin{foo2}
\begin{foo3}
\foo
\end{foo3}
\begin{foo3}
\foo
\end{foo3}
\end{foo2}

\end{document}
```

**By the way:**

**Many LaTeX documents need to be compiled several times** (at least twice) until `\tableofcontents` and all references and hyperlinks (in terms of `\label{..}` and `\ref{..}`or `\pageref{..}` work out.  If you wish to have created portions of document's text randomly, you need to **ensure that the ranom-thingie is done only during the first compilation and then is preserved for consecutive compilations**.

Otherwise you might get a never ending story:

1. (La)TeX-run yields (another) randomize-result.
2. Other ranomize-result yields other text.
3. Other text yields other pagebreaking.
4. Other pagebreaking yields other page numbers.
5. Other page numbers yield requiring another (La)TeX-run for having `\tableofcontents`and `\label`..`\ref` matching out. You are back at 1.